# Conditional merging of two dataframes in python3.7

Tags: python, pandas

I have following dataframe

```
col1    term1   term2
ab|a    ab      a
cd      cd
```

I would like to merge this dataframe to another dataframe (df2) using both the columns "term1" and "term2" but skip/ignore when it is None (like in row 2). I am trying to use if/else condition here in a for loop. Please see the pseudocode below (this is not a functional code as it is showing error as well).

Is it a right approach or there is nicer way to do this.

```
df1 = pd.concat([df["col1 
"],df["col1"].str.split("|", expand=True)], axis=1)
df1.rename(columns={0: 'term1', 1: 'term2'}, inplace=True)

for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    if row['term1'] is None:
        break
    else:
        row = row.to_frame()
        print (row)
        row.merge(df2, how = 'inner', left_on = 'term1', right_on = 'STR')
```

Comment: Can you edit your DataFrame example to something we can copy/paste to reproduce the data easily please? Also, 99% of the time if you're having to manually loop through a DataFrame you're doing it wrong. Whilst possible, it's considered an anti-pattern and will be extremely slow, in comparison, on large data sets

Answer (score 1):

A loop in pandas dataframes is a code smell. In order to exclude rows with null values, just drop them before merging. You could first use pandas' dropna ([doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html)). Something like this:

```
df1 = df1.dropna(subset=["term1", "term2"])
```

And then apply pandas' merge ([doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)):

```
df = df1.merge(df2, on=["term1", "term2"])
```

In order to make the code shorter, you could first define `merge_columns = ["term1", "term2"]` to be used in the dropna and merge method. You could also make the filter right inside the merge, I just did it step by step to be clear.

Hope it helps.